# Python graph representation

Tags: python

if I have a directed graph whose vertices are denoted by {1,2,3,...} and the connections between them are like this:(meaning there is a directed edge from b to a represented as a<-b)

```
List1: 1<-2<-3<-4<-5<-6
List2: 2<-4<-7<-6
List3: 1<-8<-7
List4: 1<-9<-2
```

The degree of vertex 4 is 2 (since it has a edge to 3 and 2), degree of 6 is 2 and so on. How can I compute this and store this in a dictionary in python as shown below:

```
dict = {}
dict{4:'2', 6:'2'}
```

like this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your actual input look like?

Comment: My input looks like this : words[] =  ['4777', '2516', '4637', '1221', '38803', '56203']. Where each element is connected by a directed edge to its previous element.

Comment: what's the degree of `7` in that input? Given `4777` and `4637`,  is it `4` or `2`?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following,

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
l2 = [2, 4, 7, 6]
l3 = [1,8,7]
l4 = [1, 9, 2]

from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)

for l in [l1, l2, l3, l4]:
    for i,n in enumerate(l):
         if i:
             d[n].append(l[i-1])
In [144]: d
Out[144]:
defaultdict(list,
        {2: [1, 9],
         3: [2],
         4: [3, 2],
         5: [4],
         6: [5, 7],
         7: [4, 8],
         8: [1],
         9: [1]})
```

You can do all the operations on `defaultdict` that you can on `dict`. So if you want to count the degrees,

```
degree = {k: len(v) for k,v in d.items()}
In [146]: degree
Out[146]: {2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 1, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 1, 9: 1}
```

Comment: hey what are 144 and 146 here? I am sorry I am new to this concept

Comment: @Nikhil They are part of the terminal prompt.Not part of code.

Comment: @Nikhil You will have `>>>` Type `>>> d` or `>>> degrees`